# Brand new iPad Pro has a year old battery, is that really ok?

Tags: ipad, battery

Greeting folks.
As stated, I picked up a new, off the shelf 12.9" iPad Pro with the M1 onboard, and as someone who uses CoconutBattery for numerous devices over some time, I took at look to see what the reported capacity and info on this battery was, and apparently it is manufactured by Sunwoda and is already 352 days old. I apologize if this is a silly question, please inform me if so, but for something so expensive and off the shelf new, isn't the battery being practically a full year old already significant? Am I losing anything in terms of longevity (daily or long-term) already being that age?

Thank you.

Comment: All the components are manufactured with a delivery time, storage time, build process time, and storage / shipping time then time it sits in the store before the day of purchase.

Answer (score 1):

Battery degradation comes from these primary sources:

- Cycle count
- Time spent at high or low states of charge
- Temperature

Cycle count would have no impact in this scenario, since the battery is old but not previously used.

This means that the battery condition really depends on how well they store them. Presumably they store them in a temperature controlled environment, and no reason to believe they don't keep them at a healthy state of charge.

This means that your battery should be perfectly fine. Be aware that 80% capacity is the warranty threshold, so if the device is impacted by this and drops below 80% within the applicable warranty period, Apple will replace it.

Answer (score -1):

The 12.9" iPad was introduced in May 2021. It's possible that the battery was manufactured *slightly* before that, but a whole five/six months seems unlikely.

What date does Coconut Battery give for the manufacture of the iPad itself? I'd be surprised if an iPad Pro had been sitting on the shelf in an Apple Store since May: stock control is tight and sales are good.

The new iPad might store the relevant info in a different way from previous iPads, and Coconut Battery could be miscalculating/mis-parsing the manufacturing date from the info it gets.  Maybe report it to the devs for checking? *(CB doesn't show the Manufacture date of my M1 MBP, nor the battery manufacturer, for example.)*

It's certainly true that batteries degrade over time, regardless of use, though I would presume that Apple has thought about the manufacture process and the effects of initial storage in the comments it makes about battery life. Check the warranty terms and statutory rights for your location.

You could always take it back for a replacement, and see if that's any better.

Comment: I seriously seriously doubt that you can get a warranty replacement for a fully functional piece of equipment just because you don't like where and when it was manufactured... If you could you could just demand such of anything you purchase a day before the warranty expires and get a brand new replacement, usually a newer model, with full warranty, forever...

Comment: @jwenting I'm certainly not suggesting that you can return something just because you 'don't like' the manufacture date. You can of course return any purchase within 14 days for any reason, and then purchase another.  There may be other statutory grounds for return and replace beyond that time frame. It certainly wouldn't hurt to ask and smile sweetly.

Comment: @benwiggy There’s no country tag on this post, and in (for example) the UK there’s no statutory right to return a product bought in a shop unless it’s defective.